# Scala - what is the right way to organize singleton objects hierarchy?

Tags: scala, inheritance, object, singleton

Here is something that I have came across in Scala that did not cause any problems in Java. Now I just do not know what is the right way of doing this in Scala.

Problem description: I have a Scala Object which denotes an 'abstract' object. It is intended to have a singletonic profile but it is not intended for real use, it is just a bunch of definitions common to it's children-singletons. So instead, I want to use it's children. So there comes the question: since I cannot inherit objects, should the common singleton functionality be realized as a class? As an abstract class? Trait does not suit me because it can't have constructors.
  If an abstract parent class would do, then how should I access it's singleton (or static) methods if I need them anythere?
  I realize that there might be a flaw in my design, but since I have this question and can't think of any definitive answer, it is interesting to hear what you say (including design alternatives).

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I think they exhaust the topic! I will go with the trait.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really should be using a `trait`; there is no need for constructors (and, indeed, they make no sense because a scala `object` has no constructor):

Here's the shared trait; `needA` is the *value you need to pass to your constructor*. That is, it is required by the functionality of the trait.

```
trait Common {
  def needA: A

  def sharedMethod { /* implement me*/ }
}
```

Then your modules look like this:

```
object Mod1 extends Common {
  val needA = { /* implement me*/ }
}     
object Mod2 extends Common {
  val needA = { /* implement me*/ }
}
```

Notice that they specify the required values for the common functionality by using a `val` to override a `def`

Comment: and if you require different implementations (e.g. mock and production variations), use cake pattern along with self types. Powerful pattern: http://jboner.github.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di.html

Answer (score 2):

Your concern is quite similar to the one that occurs in the design of the companion objects in the collection library in scala.
They choose to use a caommon trait that gather similar functionnalities for their companion objects. To go further, take a look for example at the [`GenericCompanion`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion) trait and its known subclasses.